# ftp login ok but directory listing fails after port forwarding

Tags: ftp, port-forwarding, proftpd, ubuntu-18.04

I'm making a webserver and my OS is Ubuntu 18.04. My router is an AT&T 2WIRE i38HG

I set up a FTP server using proftpd and gadmin-proftpd. When I used the computer's IP address (192.168.1.82) to log on, it worked perfectly fine but after I used port forwarding with my AT&T router, the new IP address was **PUBLIC-IP-ADDRESS**. When I went to the page **ftp://PUBLIC-IP-ADDRESS**, I logged in, but it just kept loading and nothing appeared.

Here are my server settings:

```
Server Address: 0.0.0.0
Server Port: 21
NAT Router: 192.168.1.254
Identity lookups: Off
Reverse lookups: Off
Time standard: Local time
Passive port range: 49152 - 65534
Max connections: 30
Max login attempts: 15
Login timeout: 300
Idle timeout: 600
Transfer mode: Binary
```

Here is the proftpd.conf file:

```
ServerType standalone
DefaultServer on
Umask 022
ServerName "0.0.0.0"
ServerIdent on "SeanServer0001"
ServerAdmin ****@gmail.com
IdentLookups off
UseReverseDNS off
Port 21
PassivePorts 49152 65534
MasqueradeAddress 192.168.1.254
TimesGMT off
MaxInstances 30
MaxLoginAttempts 15
TimeoutLogin 300
TimeoutNoTransfer 600
TimeoutIdle 600
DisplayLogin welcome.msg
DisplayChdir .message
User nobody
Group nobody
DirFakeUser off nobody
DirFakeGroup off nobody
DefaultTransferMode binary
AllowForeignAddress off
AllowRetrieveRestart on
AllowStoreRestart on
DeleteAbortedStores on
TransferRate RETR 1024
TransferRate STOR 1024
TransferRate STOU 1024
TransferRate APPE 1024
SystemLog /var/log/secure
RequireValidShell off
<IfModule mod_tls.c>
TLSEngine off
TLSRequired off
TLSVerifyClient off
TLSProtocol 
TLSLog /var/log/proftpd_tls.log
TLSRSACertificateFile /etc/gadmin-proftpd/certs/cert.pem
TLSRSACertificateKeyFile /etc/gadmin-proftpd/certs/key.pem
TLSCACertificateFile /etc/gadmin-proftpd/certs/cacert.pem
TLSRenegotiate required off
TLSOptions AllowClientRenegotiation
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ratio.c>
Ratios off
SaveRatios off
RatioFile "/restricted/proftpd_ratios"
RatioTempFile "/restricted/proftpd_ratios_temp"
CwdRatioMsg "Please upload first!"
FileRatioErrMsg "FileRatio limit exceeded, upload something first..."
ByteRatioErrMsg "ByteRatio limit exceeded, upload something first..."
LeechRatioMsg "Your ratio is unlimited."
</IfModule>
<Limit LOGIN>
  AllowUser test
  AllowUser seanhe
  DenyALL
</Limit>

<Anonymous /var/www/html>
User test
Group public
AnonRequirePassword on
MaxClients 10 "The server is full, hosting %m users"
DisplayLogin welcome.msg
DisplayChdir .msg
<Limit LOGIN>
Allow from All
Deny from all
</Limit>
AllowOverwrite off
<Limit LIST NLST  PWD XPWD  SIZE  STAT  CWD XCWD  CDUP XCUP >
 AllowAll
</Limit>
<Limit STOR STOU  APPE  RETR  RNFR RNTO  DELE  MKD XMKD SITE_MKDIR  RMD XRMD SITE_RMDIR  SITE  SITE_CHMOD  SITE_CHGRP  MTDM >
 DenyAll
</Limit>
</Anonymous>

<Anonymous /var/www/html>
User seanhe
Group admin
AnonRequirePassword on
MaxClients 15 "The server is full, hosting %m users"
DisplayLogin welcome.msg
DisplayChdir .msg
<Limit LOGIN>
Allow from All
Deny from all
</Limit>
AllowOverwrite on
<Limit LIST NLST  STOR STOU  APPE  RETR  RNFR RNTO  DELE  MKD XMKD SITE_MKDIR  RMD XRMD SITE_RMDIR  SITE  SITE_CHMOD  SITE_CHGRP  MTDM  PWD XPWD  SIZE  STAT  CWD XCWD  CDUP XCUP >
 AllowAll
</Limit>
<Limit NOTHING >
 DenyAll
</Limit>
</Anonymous>
```

I forwarded the ports 21 and 20 for FTP

Can somebody tell me whats wrong?

Comment: You probably want to research about passive/active mode of FTP.

Comment: Did you forward all passive ports (49152 thru 65534) to your server? What you need to do is narrow that range down to a reasonable number in the config, like 49100-49200 and forward those ports.

Comment: yes, forward those ports, and also change MasqueradeAddress to public address, that FTP server would use that to advertise their socket for data transfer
Ref: http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html

Comment: I tried to forward the port range(49152 - 65534) but I got the message: `The system web server is using the same resources.`

Comment: Turns out the problem was in the port range, there may have been ports already used by my router or other applications so all I had to do was narrow the range so that I was practically sure that the ports were free.

Comment: Hello @awesomeguy I removed your public IP address from the question. Seeing you are new to FTP and Webservers, I would recommend you be more careful when posting questions and avoid including personal and sensitive information. Try to use examples and be clear, but avoid direct links. Also, FTP is not a current way to manage a webpage, having a FTP server in your home, forwarded from your router without enough knowledge could cause a serious compromise to your network and privacy.